# How to use Query String and Anchor Hashtag in react-router app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying to use query parameters in a link with hashtag. But after i add the query params in the url the page doesn't load with the content with hashtag id in view. I search this issues and found out the correct order was

> http://www.whatever.com?var=val#anchor

I have tried this but it is not working. When the page loads it does not scroll to the section. But clicking on the links scrolls to the section.

I am using react-router-dom v4 in my app. Is there a config that enables this in react-router apps?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Harsha Venkatram Thank you for your response. And sorry i was not very clear in the question. But i have tried using link structure like this http://www.whatever.com?var=val#anchor. Which according to a lot of blogs is the right way to use hash tag and query in a url. But is not working in my react router app on page load but clicking on a link with hash tag  works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is this:

### Change

http://www.whatever.com?var=val#anchor

### To

http://www.whatever.com/#anchor?var=val

It will be much easier if you provide your work.

Comment: This works, but for some reason the anchor doesn't place the user on the right position, even if I try to use `top` to place the anchor in an arbitrary position that can make the user saw the right part of the document...